# C++ pointer arithmetic "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to create an array of pointers.  When initializing each pointer I can't use (ptr + 1) to assign something.

Example code:

```
int* demo = (int*) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int* pa = &a;
int* pb = &b;
demo = pa;
demo+=1;
demo = pb;
```

will work, while

```
int* demo = (int*) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int* pa = &a;
int* pb = &b;
demo = pa;
(demo + 1) = pb;
```

won't. It says error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" on the last line.

Is there any way to use a (for the lack of a better term) 'temporarily incremented pointer' or do I need to just store the original pointer and iterate through my array by incrementing my pointer?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `demo = malloc(...); demo = ...` is a memory leak. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: How would you expect `(demo + 1) = pb` to work? What do you think it should do?

Comment: Same situation as `int x = 0; x + 1 = 3;`. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: In fact, same situation as `int x = 0; x = 1; x += 1; x = 3;` ("working" version) and `int x = 0; x = 1; (x + 1) = 3;`.

Comment: Yes, what are you trying to do?  Contrary to popular belief, overusage of pointers does not make you a better programmer.

Comment: I just figured out i got it the wrong way. It has to be like ''' *(demo+1) = a '''
I got the referencing/dereferencing thing mixed up

Comment: @DanielEcht That's better written as `demo[1] = a` (and has nothing to do with an array of pointers).

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for that tip. What i meant was an array as a field of pointers.

Comment: @DanielEcht What do you mean by "field"? And why "of pointers"? There's only a single pointer there.

Comment: are you sure you're using c++ and not C? You would be far better off without malloc for something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an array of pointers.

Well, `int *demo` creates a single pointer, not an array of them.

If you want an array of pointers, you need to do something like:

```
int *demo[5];
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
demo[0] = &a;
demo[1] = &b;
```

Since `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x + y)` for pointers, the last two lines can also be written as

```
*(demo + 0) = &a;
*(demo + 1) = &b;
```

---

On the other hand, if you're just trying to dynamically allocate an array of integers, you can do it like this:

```
int *demo = new int[5];
demo[0] = 1;
demo[1] = 2;
// Or (as above):
// *(demo + 0) = 1;
// *(demo + 1) = 2;
...
delete[] demo;
```

But I would recommend using a standard container (such as `std::vector`) instead of calling `new[]` manually.

Answer (score 2):

So you first allocate memory and assign it to `demo`.  You next aim `demo` at `&a`, and LEAK MEMORY.  The original value, the one returned by malloc, is overwritten by `&a`, which is likely no where near that returned pointer.  Heap vs Stack.

For every `malloc`, there must be a `free`.  For every `new`, there must be a `delete`.  Your code has no `free`, and is therefor unclean.  It may only be sanctified by the holy... eh whatever.  Just don't forget to `free` your memory.

An "L-value" means "a value that is valid on the LEFT(thus the L) of an assignment".  `demo + 1` creates a temporary value, one that immediately goes away.

Pointers and arrays are entirely too interchangeable in C/C++.  It looks like what you wanted to do was `demo[0] = &a` and `demo[1] = &b`... writing values to that area that was allocated and stored in demo.  You didn't mean to write over demo itself, and whatever is next to demo itself (which happens to be `a`) with a 64 bit value (which would also tromp on `b`).

You also were writing `int*` values (a 64 bit pointer), into an array of integers (32 bit values ON MOST BUT NOT ALL platforms).

And given that this is C++, you would probably be much happier with:

```
    std::vector<int*> demo;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    demo.push_back(&a);
    demo.push_back(&b);
```

You're letting std::vector do all the allocating and freeing.  No muss, no fuss, no resource leaks.

With vectors you do have to keep some things in mind.  "room for" and "size" are not the same.

```
    std::vector<int*> badIdea();
    badIdea.reserve(5); // Preallocating is good, right?  room for 5 (or maybe a bit more).
    assert(badIdea.size() == 0);
    badIdea[0] = nullptr; // bad news. Writing into the memory but not actually changing the vector's idea of how big it is.
    assert(badIdea.size() == 0);
    badIdea.push_back(&someInt);
    assert(badIdea.size() == 1); // so &someInt was written over that nullptr
```

This becomes an even worse idea if you were using a vector of a nontrivial destructor.

```
    std::vector<someClass> reallyBadIdea;
    reallyBadIdea[0].someFunction(); // the object at [0] hasn't been constructed yet
    reallyBadIdea.push_back(stuff);
```

In the unlikely event that someFunction() didn't blow up in your face, what would happen if someFunction() allocated something that was to be deallocated in the destructor.  Because vector doesn't think there's an object in reallyBadIdea[0], it just runs someClass's copy constructor on `stuff`.  It never runs the destructor to clean up that object that didn't exist there.

So the standard containers are great, but you really have to know a couple things about them first, or you're just begging to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: this is the best answer OP could get.

Comment: `assert badIdea.size() == 0;` doesn't even compile. It's a syntax error.

Comment: The whole explanation around "room for" / "size" and preallocation is wrong. `std::vector<someClass> reallyBadIdea(1);` creates a vector of size 1, and that one element is constructed. The first example using `std::vector<int*> demo(5);` and two `push_back`s creates a seven-element vector.

Comment: That's what I get for going back and forth between C++ and Java too much.  Does this pass muster?

Comment: And that's what happens when the last two companies you worked for both had their own container classes, and then you start using std::containers again.  Oy.